Running into pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: UDF class doesn't implement any UDF interface
I am trying to utilize Scala udfs from pyspark and running into 'pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: UDF class doesn't implement any UDF interface' error
My scala code looks something like this
package com.spark.udfexample

Object test{
  case class (a: Option[String], b: Option[String])
   
    val foo: StructType = new StructType().add("a", StringType).add("b", StringType)

    def udf1:UserDefinedFunction = udf((param: String, param: Seq[Row])) {
       ...
       ...
    }
    ..
.
}


I am packing this object class as jar and passing to pyspark context.
spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("udf1", "com.spark.udfexample.test") - running into the error here, can someone help? thx

I'd suggest looking at this blog post as it gives a run down of why you are getting that error.
Your pseudo code looks to be a setup of scala udf potentially even using class state  and what the python interface is looking for is a no args public class implementing a UDFx interface.
If you can successfully register your actual scala udf function (and use it) within scala spark then you can create a function in an object to register it via scala and call that in your python code.
